GitHub actions repo name
I am trying to get repo and usernames inside of github action in my own repository. After executing
jobs:
  Publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Login to DockerHub
        run: docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }} -p ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }} $REGISTRY
      - id: get_version
        name: Get the release version
        uses: battila7/get-version-action@v2
      - name: Get image name
        run: | 
          export IMAGE_NAME=${{ github.repository }}
          echo $IMAGE_NAME
      - name: Get image tag
        run: |
          export TAG=${{ steps.get_version.outputs.version-without-v }}
          echo $TAG
      - name: Build image
        run: docker build . -t $IMAGE_NAME:$TAG

IMAGE_NAME remains to be ***/reponame and not username/reponame. My question is, why is my username replaced with stars?

To set a value in the environment, you have to use the environment file, not export.

It still remains replaced with stars.
I did
env:
   IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}


@BenjaminW. I have tried what you proposed, but the result was the same

It might be because it is the same value than an actual secret.

Ah, good point, my guess is that DOCKER_USERNAME matches.

The asterisks are just for printing in the logs, it's not the actual value.  GitHub does this to prevent your secrets from being exfiltrated.
As for why this is happening for a non-secret: Your organization name or user name must be one of the secrets, so ownername/reponame becomes ***/reponame.  Perhaps your secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME, as others proposed in the comments.
